# Pass argument to callback function

Tags: c++, arduino

I'am working with [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ZeroTimer), as you can see `setCallback` as a protoype like this `void Adafruit_ZeroTimer::setCallback(boolean enable, tc_callback cb_type,void (*callback_func)(void)){`

I would like to know if it's possible to pass arguments to callback function?

Should I change the library to accomplish that by something like that `void (*callback_func)(int n)` and create in my sketch `void my_function_callback(int n){...}` and when I create my timer `my_timer.zerotimer.setCallback(true, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0, my_function_callback(10))` ?

Comment: Callback are typically called by some kind of framework, hence the framework will pass the arguments to a function. However, yours seems to be function that takes no arguments to begin with. In other occasions one might pass a void* eg and then the framework will pass the void* to the callback. And then it is up to you to do with the framework what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding argument to the type of callback function for the argument like `void (*callback_func)(int n)` is right way.

Calling function in argument instead of passing the function like `my_timer.zerotimer.setCallback(true, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0, my_function_callback(10))` is wrong way. You should simply pass the function without calling that like `my_timer.zerotimer.setCallback(true, TC_CALLBACK_CC_CHANNEL0, my_function_callback)`.